Model Stacking - Out of Fold Procedures
I am attempting to use a model stacking procedure where I am using a time-series split on a set of data I have (around 5000 entries). The goal is binary classification.
After obtaining hyper parameters on my base models using CV on training sets - I then train my base models on in folds and store the projected probabilities of the out of fold predictions. I ultimately use these out of fold predictions as features within my meta model.
However there are some issues and questions.

When utilizing a time series split, I seem to notice that my average out of fold prediction size is significantly smaller than the amount of data in my in fold predictions. Hence, I do not have a good approach to choose the amount of folds I should use when I train/tune my meta model. For example, I have noticed that using a fold size of 10 leads my model to not have a fit at all (it projects only one classification category regardless of base model inputs). My hypothesis is that a larger amount of folds, restricts the amount of data my meta model has in order to find an optimal fit. How can I choose the optimal amount of folds?
With the current procedure I have, I am unsure of how I can calibrate my base models (using a procedure like CalibratedClassifierCV). Should I calibrate my base models before using their out of fold probabilities? Or should I only calibrate my base models after training my meta model (for the use case of my meta model features).


After some further thought, in regards to point 2 - I think I can use a CalibratedClassifierCV during my training processes for my base models, when collecting my out of fold predictions. It shouldn't have any data leakage as the calibration occurs within a holdout set within my training fold. In addition, for purposes of generating my meta model features for testing (the base model predictions), I believe its fine to use a CalibratedClassifierCV on the base models.
